# Cocoon nested_form render yourself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, apache-cocoon

I'm trying to create a form that calls itself with cocoon, question has_many questions, is generating infinite loop :(

Model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions,:foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent =>:destroy
  belongs_to :basic_component

  attr_accessible :description, :questions_attributes, :questions

end
```

my question _form

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @question] do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <div class="questions">
      <%= f.semantic_fields_for :questions do |question| %>
          <%= render 'question_fields', :f => question %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association("Nova Pergunta", f, :questions, class: 'button') %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

my _question_fields

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :description} %>
    <div class="questions">
      <%= f.semantic_fields_for :questions do |question| %>
        <%= render 'question_fields', :f => question %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association("Nova Pergunta", f, :questions, class: 'button') %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Infinite loop :(, how to solve?

```
  Rendered admin/questions/_question_fields.html.erb (168.4ms)
  Rendered admin/questions/_question_fields.html.erb (376.2ms)
  Rendered admin/questions/_question_fields.html.erb (586.4ms)
  Rendered admin/questions/_question_fields.html.erb (780.2ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `link_to_add_association` also pre-renders the nested form, at server side, so when the link is clicked, it can insert the "new" item.

So that is where your endless loop comes from: the `link_to_add_association` renders the nested-form, which also renders the nested-form and the `link_to_add_association` which also ... ad infinitum ;)

If you really want to be able to build an indefinite/unlimited tree, cocoon is not the tool for you. You will have to resort to using ajax.

However if you can limit the maximum depth, it is rather easy to add an extra parameter to the view which only renders the `link_to_add_association` if the level is below your maximum level.

This has come up before in the cocoon issues, and a possible solution was [demonstrated](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon-self_join-form/commit/8017c9ea06826f8f539acf60095120c9b26e1926)

In short, assume the maximum depth is 5, you do something like (haml for readability) :

```
= semantic_form_for [:admin, @question] do |f| 
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :description
      .questions
        = f.semantic_fields_for :questions do |question|
          = render 'question_fields', f: question, depth: 0
      .links
        = link_to_add_association "Nova Pergunta", f, :questions, 
             class: 'button', render_options: {locals: {depth: 0}}
  = f.actions
```

and your `question_fields` partial then tests for this `depth` (and propagates it)

```
.nested-fields
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :description
    .questions
      = f.semantic_fields_for :questions do |question| 
        = render 'question_fields', :f => question, depth: depth + 1
    - if depth < 5
      .links
        = link_to_add_association "Nova Pergunta", f, :questions, 
          class: 'button', render_options: {locals: {depth: depth + 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question fields, you have:

```
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :questions do |question| %>
  <%= render 'question_fields', :f => question %>
<% end %>
```

Which is causing the loop. You are calling this file over and over since you are in the file.

Comment: Yeah, Graham, I would like that when clicking on the button to load a new form, creating a tree, but it is what you said before the click, he calls the render, you know how I solve? Should I create a JavaScript? Thank you